# "To order $n$ of" arguments

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, calculus, approximations

Often one finds in physics textbooks that arguments will be made "to order $n$". I am not sure on what the procedure or argument ought to be when we have some denominator dependence though. As an example, consider the function of temperature

$$f(T) = T\frac{c(T)}{u(T)}$$
where $c(T) = A_cT + B_cT^3 + C_cT^5...$ and $u(T) = u_0 + A_uT^2 + B_uT^4+...$.
Now suppose you are told to give $f$ "to order 4". What does this mean? I often find books will do something like "take the numerator to order 4 and then keep the denominator at its zeroth order approximation". Under this procedure, we find
$$f(T) \approx T\frac{A_cT + B_cT^3}{u_0}$$
Why is this valid?

Comment: The correct way is to take the Taylor series expansion and keep terms up to the fourth order.

Comment: @flippiefanus How would you proceed when you only have the Taylor expansions of the individual functions involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be systematic, the answer is simply to compute the Taylor series. The coefficient of $T^n$ in the expansion is, as ever, given by
$$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

If you know the expansions of the numerator and denominator separately, this is straightforward (if tedious).

---

The proposal you mention certainly does not yield the correct result, can you provide a reference for it? Once you become more skilled at manipulating Taylor series, you notice that

$$\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 + \mathcal O(x^3)$$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{1+a T^2 + bT^4} = 1 - aT^2 - bT^4 + (aT^2 + bT^4)^2 + \mathcal O(T^6)$$
$$ = 1-aT^2 - bT^4 + a^2 T^4 + \mathcal O(T^6) = 1-aT^2 + (a^2-b)T^4 + \mathcal O(T^6)$$

Plugging that into the expression you have and neglecting terms of order $>4$ yields the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To connect it to what I see in textbooks, I'm wondering what happens when I'm given that denominator as an infinite series itself. For things sufficiently well-behaved, can I generalize what you have to obtain (as in my example) $$\frac{Tc(T)}{u(T)} = T(A_cT + B_cT^3 + C_cT^5...)(1-(u_0 + A_uT^2 + B_uT^4+...) + (u_0 + A_uT^2 + B_uT^4+...)^2 +...);$$
this is more or less what I meant by comment above in which I asked "How would you proceed when you only have the Taylor expansions of the individual functions involved?"

Comment: @EE18 If you're only keeping up to order 4, you can start by truncating all of the expansions at that order and then proceed from there. Note that the quantity being squared at the end of your expression does not include $u_0$.

Comment: Ah I see; you're saying that $u_0$ should have been factored out at the start to get the $1 + x$ structure of the denominator?

Comment: And can I just ask if, for general orders, my given formal structure above of just "combining" Taylor series is correct? That is, if I was interested in arbitrary orders?

Comment: @EE18 Yes, that's right. And yes, it is correct as long as you stay within the radius of convergence of both Taylor series. Try formally computing the Taylor series for $f$ and see for yourself.

Comment: @EE18 To be clear, I mean the radius of convergence for $c$ and $1/u$, not necessarily $c$ and $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and your time!